# Структура сайта Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день! Не так давно начал изучать Битрикс.

Собственно вопрос:

Есть раздел в админке - Структура сайта и там сначала идет список имеющихся сайтов

например рус, анг и третий пункт "Файлы и папки"

Почему когда я создаю например файл `test.php` через папки рус или анг его не видно, видно только папки и файл меню,

а через раздел "Файлы и папки" видно все, т.е. все файлы, которые находятся в конкретной папке.

Возникает ощущение, что через папки сайтов видны только папки без файлов

Answer (score 2):

В битриксе есть различия логической и физической структуры, вы создали файл но он не отразился в логической структуре.

Советую почитать про структуру в курсе [Контент Менеджер](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=1853) (ссылка на раздел менеджер файлов) или в курсе [Администратор Базовый](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=35&LESSON_ID=2021) (Создание страниц и разделов)